# Elastic Search Query Nested Fields - Last withdrawn Salary

Tags: elasticsearch

I am having some trouble querying my Elasticsearch index. I am trying to fetch the last known monthly salary of a person with a salary greater than 4500.

Below is the table structure of my data showing a person and their monthly salary:

```
Name |  Nested  |  StartDate   |  EndDate       | Monthy Salary
     |  Object  |              |                |
====================================================================
Raj  |  Salary  | 1-Jan-20     | 31-Dec-20      | 5000
     |          | 1-Jan-19     | 31-Dec-19      | 4000
John |  Salary  | 1-Jan-23     | 31-Dec-23      | 6000
     |          | 1-Jan-22     | 31-Dec-22      | 3000
Mary |  Salary  | 1-Jan-23     | 31-Dec-23      | 4000
     |          | 1-Jan-22     | 31-Dec-22      | 10000
Sam  |  Salary  | 1-Jan-20     | 31-Dec-20      | 2000
     |          | 1-Jan-19     | 31-Dec-19      | 5000
```

The Elasticsearch index structure

```
{
    "mappings": {
        "type_name": {
            
            "properties": {
                "name": {
                    "type": "keyword"
                },
                "salary": {
                    "type": "nested",
                    "properties": {
                        "start_date": {
                            "type": "date",
                            "format": "yyyy-MM-dd"
                        },
                        "end_date" : {
                            "type": "date",
                            "format": "yyyy-MM-dd"
                        },
                        "monthly amount": {
                            "type": "double"
                        }

                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Then create some documents in Elasticsearch:

Document1

```
{
    "name": "Raj",
    "salary": [
        {
            "start_date": "2020-01-01",
            "end_date": "2020-12-31",
            "monthly amount": 5000
        },
        {
            "start_date": "2019-01-01",
            "end_date": "2019-12-31",
            "monthly amount": 4000
        }
    ]
}
```

Document 2

```
{
    "name": "John",
    "salary": [
        {
            "start_date": "2023-01-01",
            "end_date": "2023-12-31",
            "monthly amount": 6000
        },
        {
            "start_date": "2022-01-01",
            "end_date": "2022-12-31",
            "monthly amount": 3000
        }
    ]
}
```

Document 3

```
{
    "name": "Mary",
    "salary": [
        {
            "start_date": "2023-01-01",
            "end_date": "2023-12-31",
            "monthly amount": 4000
        },
        {
            "start_date": "2022-01-01",
            "end_date": "2022-12-31",
            "monthly amount": 10000
        }
    ]
}
```

Document 4

```
{
    "name": "Sam",
    "salary": [
        {
            "start_date": "2020-01-01",
            "end_date": "2020-12-31",
            "monthly amount": 2000
        },
        {
            "start_date": "2019-01-01",
            "end_date": "2019-12-31",
            "monthly amount": 5000
        }
    ]
}
```

But when I try to execute the below query - getting the last known salary - Raj is getting skipped from the results:

```
{
    "size": 25,
    "query": {
        "bool": {
            "must": [
                {
                    "nested": {
                        "path": "salary",
                        "query": {
                            "bool": {
                                "filter": [
                                    {
                                        "range": {
                                            "salary.start_date": {
                                                "boost": 1.0,
                                                "lte": "now"
                                            }
                                        }
                                    },
                                    {
                                        "range": {
                                            "salary.end_date": {
                                                "boost": 1.0,
                                                "gt": "now"
                                            }
                                        }
                                    }
                                ],
                                "must": [
                                    {
                                        "range": {
                                            "salary.monthly amount": {
                                                "gte": 4500
                                            }
                                        }
                                    }
                                ]
                            }
                        }
                    }
                }
            ]
        }
    }
}
```

What am I missing?

Comment: Raj has no valid salary in 2023 (i.e. now), so that's why he's skipped