# Elastic Search Query Nested Fields - Last withdrawn Salary ( Future Data Added )

Tags: elasticsearch

** This is not duplicate of this question --https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77290585/elastic-search-query-nested-fields-last-withdrawn-salary

Here we have 3 kinds of data -

1. Person with salary mentioned for current time ( John & Mary )
2. Person retired/not working ...having past salary data ( Raj )
3. Person received increment letter i.e. having past, present and future salary ( Rahul )

```
Name  | Nested  |   StartDate   |   EndDate     |   Monthly Salary
      | Object  |               |               |
===== ===============================================================
Raj   | Salary  |   1-Jan-20    |   31-Dec-20   |   5000
      |         |   1-Jan-19    |   31-Dec-19   |   4000
John  | Salary  |   1-Jan-23    |   31-Dec-23   |   6000
      |         |   1-Jan-22    |   31-Dec-22   |   3000
Mary  | Salary  |   1-Jan-23    |   31-Dec-23   |   4000
      |         |   1-Jan-22    |   31-Dec-22   |   10000
Sam   | Salary  |   1-Jan-20    |   31-Dec-20   |   2000
      |         |   1-Jan-19    |   31-Dec-19   |   5000
Rahul | Salary  |   1-Jan-24    |   31-Dec-24   |   2000
      |         |   1-Jan-23    |   31-Dec-23   |   5000
      |         |   1-Jan-22    |   31-Dec-22   |   2000
```

Index Structure

```
{
    "mappings": {
        "type_name": {
            
            "properties": {
                "name": {
                    "type": "keyword"
                },
                "salary": {
                    "type": "nested",
                    "properties": {
                        "start_date": {
                            "type": "date",
                            "format" : "yyyy-MM-dd"
                        },
                        "end_date" : {
                            "type" : "date",
                            "format" : "yyyy-MM-dd"
                        },
                        "monthly amount" : {
                            "type" : "double"
                        }

                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

created documents for above sample data -

Document1

```
{
    "name": "Raj",
    "salary": [
        {
            "start_date": "2020-01-01",
            "end_date": "2020-12-31",
            "monthly amount": 5000
        },
        {
            "start_date": "2019-01-01",
            "end_date": "2019-12-31",
            "monthly amount": 4000
        }
    ]
}
```

Document 2

```
{
    "name": "John",
    "salary": [
        {
            "start_date": "2023-01-01",
            "end_date": "2023-12-31",
            "monthly amount": 6000
        },
        {
            "start_date": "2022-01-01",
            "end_date": "2022-12-31",
            "monthly amount": 3000
        }
    ]
}
```

Document 3

```
{
    "name": "Mary",
    "salary": [
        {
            "start_date": "2023-01-01",
            "end_date": "2023-12-31",
            "monthly amount": 4000
        },
        {
            "start_date": "2022-01-01",
            "end_date": "2022-12-31",
            "monthly amount": 10000
        }
    ]
}
```

Document 4

```
{
    "name": "Sam",
    "salary": [
        {
            "start_date": "2020-01-01",
            "end_date": "2020-12-31",
            "monthly amount": 2000
        },
        {
            "start_date": "2019-01-01",
            "end_date": "2019-12-31",
            "monthly amount": 5000
        }
    ]
}
```

Document 5

```
{
    "name": "Rahul",
    "salary": [
        {
            "start_date": "2024-01-01",
            "end_date": "2024-12-31",
            "monthly amount": 6000
        },
        {
            "start_date": "2023-01-01",
            "end_date": "2023-12-31",
            "monthly amount": 3000
        },
                {
            "start_date": "2022-01-01",
            "end_date": "2022-12-31",
            "monthly amount": 2000
        }

    ]
}
```

I am trying to fetch persons whose last withdrawn monthly salary is greated than 4500.

Below query is skipping Raj from results ...

```
{
  "size": 25,
  "query": {
    "bool": {
      "must": [
        {
          "nested": {
            "path": "salary",
            "query": {
              "bool": {
                "filter": [
                  {
                    "range": {
                      "salary.start_date": {
                        "boost": 1,
                        "lte": "now"
                      }
                    }
                  },
                  {
                    "range": {
                      "salary.end_date": {
                        "boost": 1,
                        "gt": "now"
                      }
                    }
                  }
                ],
                "must": [
                  {
                    "range": {
                      "salary.monthly amount": {
                        "gte": 4500
                      }
                    }
                  }
                ]
              }
            }
          }
        }
      ]
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: Raj has no salary specified valid "now", so that's why he's skipped